# Sum all child balance of an array into parent

Tags: php, arrays

```
     8 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Expenses"
        "is_group" => 1
        "parent_id" => 0
        "account_code" => 100
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => null
        "opening_credit_amount" => null
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ]
      9 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Direct material"
        "is_group" => 1
        "parent_id" => 100
        "account_code" => 1001
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => null
        "opening_credit_amount" => null
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ]
      10 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Import Raw Material"
        "is_group" => 0
        "parent_id" => 1001
        "account_code" => 10011
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => null
        "opening_credit_amount" => null
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ]
      11 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Local Raw Material"
        "is_group" => 0
        "parent_id" => 1001
        "account_code" => 10012
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => null
        "opening_credit_amount" => null
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ]
      12 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Direct Labor"
        "is_group" => 1
        "parent_id" => 100
        "account_code" => 1002
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => null
        "opening_credit_amount" => null
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ]
      13 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Wages"
        "is_group" => 0
        "parent_id" => 1002
        "account_code" => 10021
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => 1000.00
        "opening_credit_amount" => 2000.00
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ] 
    14 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Non Current Asset"
        "is_group" => 1
        "parent_id" => 0
        "account_code" => 101
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => null
        "opening_credit_amount" => null
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ]
    15 => array:11 [▼
        "account_name" => "Asset Revolution"
        "is_group" => 0
        "parent_id" => 101
        "account_code" => 101001
        "head_code" => null
        "debit_amount" => null
        "credit_amount" => null
        "opening_debit_amount" => 1000.00
        "opening_credit_amount" => 2000.00
        "closing_debit" => null
        "closing_credit" => null
      ]
```

> I have an array like this of a parent child account array i want to sum the child amount into parents array amount columns ..
> so far i have tried to do like this

$sql_data = above array with lots of more array like that

```
    $array = $sql_data
            foreach ($array as $datum){
                $first_code = "$datum[account_code]";
                $new_data = array_map(function($item) use($first_code){
                    if (strpos($item['account_code'], $first_code)!==false && $item['is_group']==0) {
                        return $item;
                    }
                },$array);
                if (strpos($first_code, $first_code) !== false) {
                    $account_data[$first_code] = [
                        'parent_id'=>$datum['parent_id'],
                        'account_name'=>$datum['account_name'],
                        'account_code'=>$datum['account_code'],
                        'head_code'=>$datum['head_code'],
                        'is_group'=>$datum['is_group'],
                        'debit_amount'=>array_sum(array_column($new_data,'debit_amount')),
                        'credit_amount'=>array_sum(array_column($new_data,'credit_amount')),
                        'opening_debit_amount'=>array_sum(array_column($new_data,'opening_debit_amount')),
                        'opening_credit_amount'=>array_sum(array_column($new_data,'opening_credit_amount')),
                        'closing_debit'=>array_sum(array_column($new_data,'closing_debit')),
                        'closing_credit'=>array_sum(array_column($new_data,'closing_credit'))
                    ];
                }
            }
```

the main problem is its calculating all the data where it finds 100 for the parent account 100 at the top
how to add only its child array column sum into parent column.
and is_group = 1 means that one is parent account and 0 means its a child account.

Comment: Did you check this line `if (strpos($first_code, $first_code) !== false) {`?

Comment: this is the one that checking for the code from any position but i want to check the string  only from first position to match the second $first_code in the strpos() not from anywhere of the  string

Comment: Found the solution
````
$first_code_len = strlen($first_code);
      if (substr($item['account_code'],0,$first_code_len)==$first_code) {
               return $item;
       }
````
have to use this inside the array map..